# Android use cellphone to control laptop's volume via Wifi sample code

Tags: android, controls, wifi

I'm looking for how to use an android phone to force laptop to do something via Wifi such as control volume. 
It might be need to use socket and robot also Wifimanger? But I do not how to implement that. Does anyone can provide a sample code for studying? I will very appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

gmote has this functionality, and much much more. IT is also open sourced so it might be a good thing for you to dig in to.

http://code.google.com/p/gmote/